# Django QuerySet result with null fields in results

Tags: django, null, many-to-many, duplicates

I have to get a QuerySet with many-to-many relations with the same number of results as if I executed the query in the database, but can't manage how to do this; I don't care if I can get the results as a QuerySet item or as a values item, but I do care to get the same number of results.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class House(models.Model):
    people = models.ManyToMany(Person)
    cars = models.ManyToMany(Car)


house_1 = House.objects.create()
house_2 = House.objects.create()

john = Person.objects.create(name='John')
mary = Person.objects.create(name='Mary')

house_1.people.add(john)
house_1.people.add(mary)

mike = Person.objects.create(name='Mike')
ferrari = Car.objects.create(name='Ferrari')

house_2.people.add(mike)
house_2.cars.add(ferrari)

'''

Expected search result, regardless of the result format (model instances or values):
------------------------------------
| House ID | Car      | Person     |
| 1        |          | John       |
| 1        |          | Mary       |
| 2        | Ferrari  | Mike       |
------------------------------------

'''
```

How can I get a list of values, with all 3 results, spanning multiple tables, as here?

I need this so that I can create a report which can potentialy contain null fields, so the duplicated results must be listed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write SQL query that does that. You can't because it's wrong query to that data structure. Imagine that there will be 2 cars assigned to house 1. Should it be `1-[car-1]-John`, `1-[car-2]-Merry` or `1-[car-2]-John`, `1-[car-1]-Merry`?

Comment: It's indeed a strange situation, Tomasz, but the case was that I had to change the implementation in the project I was working on from raw SQL to Django's ORM. With raw SQL they managed to return columns with null values, and theses were the cases I had to catch using ORM.

Comment: But the situation, now, is that last week I quit my job. So I'll just consider this an awkward scenario and hope not to have to deal with gigantic raw SQL inside an application again in my life. Thanks for the help! ;-)